# Data Modelling and Functional dependency

Tags: sql, database, dependencies, modeling

I am trying to decompose the relations depending on functional dependency. I have one attribute that is neither a dependent/determinant nor a part of it. I am not sure how to put it in a relation, can you please help me?

My set is { A, B, C, D, E}

A -> C D
A -> E
B is neither a dependent nor it is a determinant. How should I include B while decomposing it into relations? Should it be a part of any relation?